# Is there a way of adding a tooltip above one of the bootstrap carousel indicators?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking at the standard bootstrap full page carousel http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full-slider/ and carousel indicators are defined as:

```
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
```

I know it's relatively easy to add a tooltip for example to a button by writing:

```
<button class="btn btn-simple" id="mybutton" data-toggle="tooltip"
 data-placement="top" data-original-title="Text of tooltip">
```

but is there a way of adding a tooltip to one of the three dots/indicators of carousel? I tried writing:

```
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" data-toggle="tooltip"
 data-placement="top" data-original-title="Text of tooltip"></li>
```

but the tooltip is not visible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

> **Opt-in functionality**
>   For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning you must initialize them yourself.

```
$(function () {
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

To add triggers:

```
$('IDHERE').tooltip({
    trigger: 'manual'
})
```

> How tooltip is triggered - click | hover | focus | manual. You may pass multiple triggers; separate them with a space. manual cannot be combined with any other trigger.

Comment: wow it does work now, thank you! however, the tooltip is visible only on hover, but is there a way of making it permanent (visible always) - preferably with some kind of animation so it's more visible on the page?

Comment: Use triggers: "How tooltip is triggered - click | hover | focus | manual. You may pass multiple triggers; separate them with a space. manual cannot be combined with any other trigger." I've edited my answer to show where they are placed.